# Internet Explorer 6 (urgh) and CSS - applying multiple classes to a style

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I would like to know how well does Internet Explorer 6 interpret the following:

```
p img.blue, p img.red {
  border:(purple) 1px solid; /* (Please ignore any style errors) */
}
```

What I am interested in the application of multiple classes to the same style. I know that IE6 does not interpret the following correctly:

```
p img.blue.red {
  border:(purple) 1px solid; /* (Please ignore any style errors) */
}
```

Does anyone know a bit about this? Regards and TIA.

// edit:

Please note, I am enquiring about the first block of code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IE interprets

p img.blue, p img.red { /* */ }

correctly, by applying the contained styles to img elements with class="blue" which are children of p elements, **or** img elements with class="red" which are children of p elements.

IE doesn't understand p img.blue.red, it would only apply the style to p img.red

Answer (score 1):

I'll just quote Ryan Brill:

> IE6 doesn't understand the chain of classes within a CSS selector, but rather only reads the last class

- http://www.ryanbrill.com/archives/multiple-classes-in-ie/

Comment: So, if I understand you correctly, it interprets:
  p img.blue, p img.red {
    border:(purple) 1px solid; /* (Please ignore any style errors)*/
  }

as 
  p img.red {
    border:(purple) 1px solid; /* (Please ignore any style errors)*/
  }

Is this correct?

Comment: No, it interprets p img.blue, p img.red correctly (.blue *or* .red). It interprets p img.blue.red incorrectly (p img.red)